# Base 64 decode to String not as expected

Tags: java, base64

I have a String that I want to decode to a binary object (BigInteger or its String)
Say for instance I got the String

```
String str = "LTEwMTAwMTEwMTExMA==";
```

An now I want to decode it using the Base64.getDecoder() method, such as:

```
String result = new BigInteger(Base64.getDecoder().decode(str.getBytes("UTF-8"))).toString(2);
```

According to that, the value of result is

> 101101001100010011000000110001001100000011000000110001001100010011000000110001001100010011000100110000

which does not match with the result that I obtain using any online decoder:

> -101001101110

Could you please help me? what am I doing wrong?
Thank you very much!

Comment: When you decode that text online, you are getting the String `-101001101110`. When you call `new BigInteger(...)` you're using the values of the bytes which make up the characters in that string as a binary number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an issue with your String conversions - try this instead:

```
String result = new BigInteger(new String(Base64.getDecoder().decode(encoded.getBytes("UTF-8")))).toString();
```

By converting the byte array to String using a new String constructor you're getting a simple String representation which BigInteger constructor knows how to parse. The result will be the expected `-101001101110`

Answer (score 2):

[`Base64.Decoder.decode()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.Decoder.html#decode-java.lang.String-) produces a byte array, not a string, so you need to convert it. Then you can use the `BigInteger` constructor that accepts a radix to specify base 2:

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Base64;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        String str = "LTEwMTAwMTEwMTExMA==";
        String str2 = new String(Base64.getDecoder().decode(str), "UTF-8");
        BigInteger big = new BigInteger(str2, 2);
        System.out.println(big.toString(2));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
-101001101110
```